# reset image in tableView imageCell is blurry

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nscell

i'm trying to show an 'info' icon during a cursor 'rollover' on an `NSTableView` cell. i'm getting a copy of the cell's image, drawing the 'info' icon on it, and telling the cell to setImage with this copy. just drawing the icon will scale it and it won't be the same size in every one as the images in the table are different sizes. i'm not having a problem with the scaling or positioning the correct size icon.

my problem is that the replaced image is slightly **blurry** and it's edges are **not crisp** on close examination. the lack of edge makes it appear to be 'moving' slightly when the mouseEntered happens and the image is replaced.

i've tried a number of drawing techniques that doen't use `lockFocus` on an `NSImage` (drawing in `CGBitmapContext`, or using `CIFilter` compositing), and they produce the same results.

i'm using `NSTableView`'s `preparedCellAtColumn` as it seems that drawing in `willDisplayCell` is unpredictable -- i read somewhere but can't remember where.

here is my **`preparedCellAtColumn`** method:

```
- (NSCell *)preparedCellAtColumn:(NSInteger)column row:(NSInteger)row
{
        NSCell *cell = [super preparedCellAtColumn:column row:row];

        if ((self.mouseOverRow == row) && column == 0) {

            NSCell * imageCell = [super preparedCellAtColumn:0 row:row];

            NSImage *sourceImage = [[imageCell image] copy];        
            NSRect cellRect = [self frameOfCellAtColumn:0 row:row];
            NSSize cellSize = cellRect.size; 

            NSSize scaledSize = [sourceImage proportionalSizeForTargetSize:cellSize];

            NSImage *outputImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:cellSize];
            [outputImage setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];

            NSPoint drawPoint = NSZeroPoint;
            drawPoint.x = (cellSize.width - scaledSize.width) * 0.5;
            drawPoint.y = (cellSize.height - scaledSize.height) * 0.5;

            NSRect drawRect = NSMakeRect(drawPoint.x, drawPoint.y, scaledSize.width, scaledSize.height);

            NSPoint infoPoint = drawPoint;
            infoPoint.x += NSWidth(drawRect) - self.infoSize.width;

            [outputImage lockFocus]; 
            [sourceImage drawInRect:drawRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
            [self.infoImage drawAtPoint:infoPoint fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
            [outputImage unlockFocus];

            [cell setImage:outputImage];
        }

        return cell;
}
```

[this is the enclosed scaling method from scott stevenson]

```
- (NSSize)proportionalSizeForTargetSize:(NSSize)targetSize
{
    NSSize imageSize = [self size];
    CGFloat width  = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;

    CGFloat targetWidth  = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

    CGFloat scaleFactor  = 0.0;                
    CGFloat scaledWidth  = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

    if ( NSEqualSizes( imageSize, targetSize ) == NO )
    {    
        CGFloat widthFactor;
        CGFloat heightFactor;

        widthFactor  = targetWidth / width;
        heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if ( widthFactor < heightFactor )
            scaleFactor = widthFactor;
        else
            scaleFactor = heightFactor;

        scaledWidth  = width  * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;
    }

    return NSMakeSize(scaledWidth,scaledHeight);

}
```

i need to support 10.6, so can't use new groovy lion methods.

thanks for your consideration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is setting the origin of the image to non-integral coordinates. That means that the edge of the image will not be pixel-aligned, producing a fuzzy result.

You just need to do this:

```
NSPoint drawPoint = NSZeroPoint;
drawPoint.x = round((cellSize.width - scaledSize.width) * 0.5);
drawPoint.y = round((cellSize.height - scaledSize.height) * 0.5);
```

That will ensure the image origin has no fractional component.

Comment: thanks, Rob. oddly this works for images scaled to fit the height of the cell, but the 'blur' still exists for a scaled image that is less than the height but filling the width. i'm marking this answered, because i think that it's pointing out another problem, which might have to do with view origin coordinates and scaling, which would be a different question.